# How can be Trinity Eternal?

Tags: matthew, paul-apostle, ephesians, trinity

It's said in *Summa Theologica* that the trinity ist eternal, three persons each one being G'd a well known fact in Christianism. I'd like to know, what is the greek explanation or the following (**Matthew 28:19**) and if it was very changed (by translation):

> Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the
> name of the **Father** and of the **Son** and of the **Holy Spirit**, (ESV)

And we see a distinction amongst three words, why this happens if indeed G'd is One, and why would it be that they would be G'd if G'd is **One**, Aquinas says that He is one times one times one, this is, He isn't three as a number, but I'd like to point out that even though this seems true, isn't there a dialectic thinking in this?

And in **Ephesians 4:6** the following, just as a reflection:

> One God and Father of all, who is over all and through all and in all.

More, I'd like to add the following: *if G'd is One, then isn't everything and everyone G'd? For if they weren't Him, then He wouldn't be One (the contrapositive)*, then if this stands, meaning that there is just Him, why is there a perception of evil which isn't Him?

*obs.: the title is called if trinity is eternal as a way to say if it's the reality that trinity attempts to explain or G'd He Himself in an absolute manner*

Comment: >if G'd is One, then isn't everything and everyone G'd? Just because there is only one Elvis doesn't mean that everyone is Elvis.

Comment: But if there more than one G'd, then it's idolatry.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo: And what does this have to do with the above quote, to which I've provided a perfectly logical answer ?

Comment: I didn't upvote nor downvoted, but I think it should be more complete also, and even if your answer is logical, G'd isn't the only one, for if He was the only we are comparing to some other deity, so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo: **(1).** *I didn't upvote nor downvoted* - I never said *you* did. **(2).** *it doesn't make sense.* - The only thing not making sense is your post. You mention eternity in the question's title, but the question itself has little or nothing to do with the concept of eternity. Then you make utterly bizarre statements, similar to asking *if there is only one wolf, why isn't everyone a wolf* ? :-\

Comment: @JoãoVíctorMelo: Your recently added "explanation" for the title is unintelligible; a possible solution would be to *carefully* use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com), by [re]typing, in your own native language (presumably Portuguese), with proper punctuation, and without any abbreviations or grammatical errors, the text you want to have translated into English, then copy paste it here; hopefully, it would do the trick.

Comment: There are at least 5 different questions here:
**1** How can the Trinity be eternal?
**2** Is 28:19 mistranslated?
**3** Did Aquinas use dialectic thinking?
**4** If God is one, why isn't everyone?
**5** Is evil a part of God?
Stack Exchange sites require that each Question be a single question.
Please choose one, and ask that one question, without mentioning the others.

Answer (score 4):

The Trinity doctrine is a way of expressing who God is, for Christians. It is a form of words that grapples with the concept of the inconceivable - the being of the one God who is Almighty, who is infinite, who is Spirit, and who is Creator of everything. We are finite creatures who come into existence at a certain point in time, then who die. We are mortals. Deity is immortal.

This means that if Deity is immortal (having no beginning and no end), and that Deity is triune in being, then the triune God is eternal. That answers your question.

However, you then go on to ask two more questions which indicate that you do not know what the Trinity doctrine teaches/says about the one God whom Christians worship. You need to sort out in what sense God is one. I suggest you ask a separate question on that (though it's already been answered here on Stack, both in Hermeneutics and in the Christianity sites.) Your other question about "the perception of evil" also requires to be dealt with separately. You are jumping from one thought to another, but if you gain clarity first on what the Trinity doctrine actually says (and does not say), you will be in a better position to tackle these other deep matters.

Comment: Your answer to be right need to have concepts inside it to prove your point, why everything is or not Him.

Comment: @Joao Victor Melo  The concept I state - "if Deity is immortal (having no beginning and no end), and that Deity is triune in being, then the triune God is eternal" - is a matter of simple logic. If you don't think it is logical, then you must down-vote me accordingly. But I do not need to add one concept on top of another when the concept is a matter of logic. You either agree it is logical, or you do not. I have already said why I am not going on to your further Qs.